# App crashes on regain focus

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios-simulator

I am getting a strange behavior when I reopen my app after it loses focus from the home button.  On the simulator the app screen goes black for 5 seconds or more before the application is resumed. On the test device, the application either does the long delay or quits entirely and resets to starting state. I have put NSLog debug comments in the “applicationWillEnterForeground” and “applicationDidBecomeActive” but these only appear after the long delay so I will assume for now that nothing in these functions cause this delay.

I am using the following components in my program:
* a Tab Bar Controller
* 2 Timers, the Map kit
* IP socket streams
* 24 ViewControllers strung together on a storyboard. 
* quite a few background images and image buttons

I would happily post code if I know what parts of the program was causing this error, but as it is I am clueless. Has anyone else experienced this type of error? Do any of the components I have listed have a history of causing similar errors?

I was quite far in development when this bug was discovered and I did not test for loss of focus via home button during the incremental development process. Other, smaller projects (which used sockets and timers) did not suffer from the same bug on the same test hardware.

I am using “applicationWillResignActive” to disable the timers, and close the streams. I am using “applicationDidBecomeActive” to restart the timers, and reopen the streams. The delay is occurring before “applicationWillEnterForeground” and “applicationDidBecomeActive” is run. Further more I tried disabling the code that initiates the streams and timers, but this did not have any effect on the bug.

I am using xCode4.4.1, ios6, and am building exclusively for iPads.

Comment: Any code you have that sets initial variables should be in `viewDidLoad` or `awakeFromNib` ... It sounds like you've put your initial variable setting code in something else that is triggered when the app "regains" focus... wherever you are initially setting your variables I would move that into a `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: I forgot to mention the app loads in under 1 second, it is only the reload process that is hanging for over five secconds or crashing entirely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that the debugger is playing tricks with your mind regarding when it shows that you hit a breakpoint and the code execution of applicationWillEnterForeground.  I suggest you commit your most recent code to source control and start deleting sections one at a time till you see the behavior go away.

Comment: I was afraid I was going to have to do this, I posted here to see if someone could narrow down which part of the program I should delete first. Speaking of deleting, do I have to deleting stuff in the story board, or can I just make them inaccessible. Same goes for classes in the code, can I just comment out all references to it or must the source file be deleted entirely?

Comment: personally I would start commenting out the timers and code based objects first.  I don't have a much experience with story boards but here's a trick I've used in my app to understand the state of views: Put a break point in viewdidload or another "view lifecycle" function.  then type this into the debugger "po [[self navigationController] viewControllers]".  This will show you all the stacked view controllers.  Do this at various parts and see if the number of views affects the load time

Comment: I found the problem, on applicationWillResignActive I wrote a bunch of data to NSUserDefaults. This caused the applicationWillResignActive to not complete before the app shut down and caused the reload to fail. The app now reloads successfully with the NSUserDefaults call disabled. I am going to move this functionality to a save button the user can hit while the app is running. Thank you for your assistance portforwardpodcast.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think that reading defaults is very cheap. You should read the exiting defaults and only write the changed ones. This might reduce the time spent enough for you to avoid the explicit save button

Comment: It was creating a massive XML string and saving it to defaults.

Comment: You can breakup each XML element into a string with a unique key, and save it using NSUserDefaults.  Then you can easily check if that specific element has changed.  Also you should only call synchronize one time if possible.  Here are some simple examples:   http://codeexamples.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/nsuserdefaults-example/  You can even simplify things by only breaking up the top level elements.